# DynamoDB Update Expression For list in a Map

Tags: database, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have following dynamoDB Schema:

```
{
    "Id": {"N": "789"},
    "ProductCategory": {"S": "Home Improvement"},
    "productReviews": {
        "M": {
            "FiveStar": {
                "L": [
                    { "S": "Best product ever!" }
                ]
            },
          "FourStar": {
                "L": [
                    { "S": "Good product" },
                  { "S": "Another Review" }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically I have a map `productReviews` which has key as - "FourStar", "FiveStar", "TwoStar" etc. and value as List of reviews.

I want add new reviews to this table i.e. if a fiveStar reviews comes I will add/append it in the list of 'FiveStar' of `productReviews`. If a key does not exist in the map, I would like to just append the key value.

Is this possible in DynamoDB or I have to merge the list on my own and then update at each write.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET

Answer (score 0):

If you want this model, you'll need to merge and update on your own.

It might be simpler to make each star value its own item (give them all the same PK with an SK indicative of the star value) so you can update them directly as a single item with a string list to append to.

Depending on your access patterns, you might even want each review as its own item (still under the same PK). For example, if the item gets a thousand reviews coming in over time, you don't want to repeatedly update an ever growing item if you can just blindly add a small item each time.

On retrieval it'll still be efficient with a Query for the PK.